# Creating a Google Analytics segment to only include traffic from one source

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, subdomain, google-analytics-filters

I have a site that has problems with traffic from facebook. I want to create a segment that only includes traffic from Facebook and all subdomains. I currently have the below string but it doesn't include traffic from facebook.com or www.facebook.com

```
^((m\.facebook\.com)|(l\.facebook\.com)|(lm\.facebook\.com)|(\.facebook\.com))$
```

What is the best way to create a string that will include traffic from the below domains and subdomains?

```
facebook.com
m.facebook.com
l.facebook.com
facebook
lm.facebook.com
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the regex engine, but try `^((m|l|lm)\.)?facebook(\.com)?$`

That is:
* at first of string (`^`)
* optionnally, either `m`, `l`, or `lm`, followed by a dot
* then `facebook` mandatory
* then `.com` optionnally
* end of string `$`

It may match more than you want (ex: `l.facebook` will match) but maybe not a real problem either.
If it is a problem, then instead:

```
^(facebook|((m|l|lm)\.)?facebook\.com)$
```